# multiplication and group by in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a collection as follow in mongodb :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54901212f315dce7077204af"),
"Date" : ISODate("2014-10-20T04:00:00.000Z"),
"Type" : "Twitter",
"Entities" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : 2,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 20,
            "Neutral" : 1
        },
        {
        "ID" : 1,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 1,
            "Neutral" : 1
        }
    },
     {
        "ID" : 3,
        "Name" : "test1",
        "Sentiment" : {
            "Value" : 2,
            "Neutral" : 1
        }
]
```

}

and I have couple of them , for example in date 2014-10-20 you might find 5 tweets each of which have different value for sentiment, now what I want to do is to group by date and then get the sum of sentiment value for each date multiply it by the number of collections for each date, for example if  we have 2 collections in 2014-10-20 with sentiment values of 20,1,2 like the collection showed above  and just 5 for another collection then the value for 2014-10-20 is (20+1+2+5)*3(because this tweet is repeated for 3 entites)* 2(because we have 2 tweets document in this date)=168 , if I do not consider frequency of collections my code works well as follow :

```
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities"); // "$unwind" converts object with array into many duplicate objects, each with one from array
    collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$Date");
   groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("Date", 1));
    stages.add(unwind);
    stages.add(groupBy);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id",0);
    project.put("Date","$_id");
     project.put("value",1);
     stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project",project));
    stages.add(sort);
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(stages);
```

Now the result for for example 2014-10-20 returns 28 but I want 168 
can anyone help me ?

Update : the last version of the code that I used is as follow:

```
DBCollection collectionG;
    collectionG = db.getCollection("GraphDataCollection");
    List<DBObject> stages = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    ArrayList<DBObject> andArray = null;
         DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$_id");
            groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
            groupFields.put("date", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$Date"));
            DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
            stages.add(groupBy);
            DBObject groupByDate = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$date");
            groupByDate.put("value",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$value"));
            groupByDate.put("count",new BasicDBObject("$sum",1));
            DBObject dtGrp = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupByDate );
            stages.add(dtGrp);

            DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id",1);
            project.put("value",new BasicDBObject("$multiply",
                                            new Object[]{"$value","$count"}));
            stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project",project));
            AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(stages);
            System.out.println(output.results());
```

Comment: You have not `unwinded` the `Entities` field. That should be the first stage.

Comment: @BatScream Thanks a lot yes it worked, just a quick question I understood all you did except the purpose of $first even I looked at documentation of mongodb for that but it is very confusing can you explain what it does?

Comment: @BatScream Just another quick question, I am trying to have the result sorted by date so I added the following line at the end before aggregation but it does not sort . what is the problem with that?

Comment: @BatScream Even If you prefer I can post it as an another question?

Comment: @BatScream Thank you do not bother yourself I got it : DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
       stages.add(sort);

Comment: Yeah sure. You could definitely. You could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unwind` Entities:

```
    DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$Entities");
    stages.add(unwind);
```

`Group` by `_id` to find the sum of all the Entities sentiment values **per document**.

```
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$_id");
    groupFields.put("value", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$Entities.Sentiment.Value"));
    groupFields.put("date", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$Date"));
    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
    stages.add(groupBy);
```

`Group` by `Date` now, to get the sum of total Entities Value, and the `count` of documents **per group**.

```
    DBObject groupByDate = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$date");
    groupByDate.put("value",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$value"));
    groupByDate.put("count",new BasicDBObject("$sum",1));
    DBObject dtGrp = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupByDate );
    stages.add(dtGrp);
```

`Project` value as the multiplicative result of `count` and `value`, for each group.

```
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id",1);
    project.put("value",new BasicDBObject("$multiply",
                                    new Object[]{"$value","$count"}));
    stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project",project));
```

In case your dates differ by milliseconds, you need to group by the date, year and month together, in the second group stage and add a sort stage if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I do not know why everything return as 0 :[ { "_id" : { "$date" : "2014-10-20T04:00:00.000Z"} , "value" : 0} , { "_id" : { "$date" : "2014-10-21T04:00:00.000Z"} , "value" : 0} , { "_id" : { "$date" : "2014-10-14T04:00:00.000Z"} , "value" : 0}]

Comment: @HamedMinaee Can you update your post with the latest code you tried?

Comment: @HamedMinaee - you have missed out the first `unwind` step.

Comment: Thanks a lot yes it worked, just a quick question I understood all you did except the purpose of $first even I looked at documentation of mongodb for that but it is very confusing can you explain what it does?

Comment: @HamedMinaee When you unwind a single document by one of its fields, that is an array -> You get `n` copies of the same document. Where `n` is the number of elements in the array field based on which the `unwind` operation took place. In each copy of the document, all the fields are same except the array field element. Each copy of the document contains only one element from the array. Now when you group by the document `_id`, all these copies need to be merged together. But since all the fields are common to all the copies, we choose only the field of the $first or $last copy. Got it?

Comment: So since the date is equal for all after unwidinding we just use the first date content for merging am I right?

Comment: @HamedMinaee Yes absolutely. Spot on.